# Are there any user friendly ways to access screenshots taken on the Switch?

Tags: nintendo-switch

I have an SD card on my console and have it set to store screenshots on the card.  But it doesn't seem like there's a way to view or otherwise extract those screenshots without having to pull out the SD card and use a reader to access them.  But this is not a desirable option since the Switch has to be turned off before removing the card.  Connecting the Switch to a (Windows) computer doesn't work, it's recognized as a USB device but nothing else.  I can't imagine how it would work if I didn't have an SD card.

How else are we expected to access these screenshots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [November 30<sup>th</sup>, 2020](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22525#v1100), users can now wirelessly transfer photos and videos from their Nintendo Switch to a smart device if they are running Version 11.0.0 of the Nintendo Switch software:

> - Users can wirelessly connect their smart devices to Nintendo Switch to transfer the screenshots and videos saved within their Album.
> - For screenshots, users can transfer a maximum of 10 screenshots and 1 video capture at once.
>   *To connect, users must use their smart device to scan the QR Code displayed on the Nintendo Switch screen.

[image: Screenshot screenshot]

[image: QR Code]

Comment: Hmm, had to restart my phone for it to work.

Answer (score 10):

Currently the only way to get images off of the Switch is to either, as you mentioned, turn it off before removing the SD Micro card, or by sending them directly to social media.

I have seen a couple people on Twitter apologize for several Switch tweets in a row just because it's the easiest way for them to retrieve the images.

Comment: Oh right social media... that's not something I would consider as a solution. That's for sharing.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer The process isn't much different from my PS4. The Switch does need to be turned off before removing the SD Micro because the console actively uses it for save games and update data, even for physical Game Cards. The PS4 doesn't need to be turned off, however I need to dig through menus before manually selecting which images I want to transfer to USB. Frankly, they both leave much to be desired if direct to social media is not the desired method.

Comment: I almost want to make a new private twitter account just to use as an image dump.

Comment: I'd be lying if I said that I didn't consider the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a Facebook account, you can configure the Switch's post sharing settings to use **Only Me** when linking your account for the first time.

This allows you to upload your screenshots to Facebook without sharing them publicly. Once uploaded, you can login on your PC, save the screenshot, and delete the post.

[image: Facebook privacy - only me]

---

If you've already linked your Facebook account, [you can still edit your privacy settings afterwards](https://www.facebook.com/help/218345114850283?helpref=about_content).

> To edit the privacy and settings for your apps and games:
>
> 1. Click ▼ in the top right of Facebook and select **Settings**.
> 2. Click **Apps** in the left menu.
> 3. Click an app or game to edit its settings.
> 4. Click **Save**.

[image: Facebook - Privacy settings]

Comment: Oooh, that's interesting. Does that only apply to the Switch uploading to Facebook? Or anything uploading to Facebook? I don't remember seeing it ask who to share to when I linked, and so far I haven't attempted to upload to Facebook.

Comment: @JeffMercado Facebook lets you adjust posting permissions individually on an app-by-app basis. I've edited my answer with more detail.